# What would be good tags to distinguish between manual puzzle creation and computer generation?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now we're using [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) both for writing puzzles by hand and for computer generation. It'd be good to distinguish, but I'm unsure how.

Some ideas:

- Keep [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) for all, and add something like [authoring](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authoring) and [generating](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generating).
- Introduce [puzzle-generation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-generation) for computer generation, and something new or [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) for hand-writing puzzles.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

- [creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creation) covers all types of puzzle creation. ("puzzle" is somewhat redundant on this site.)
- [algorithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) covers automated methods. Questions with both [creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creation) and [algorithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) are for generating puzzles algorithmically.
- [manual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual) could be used (if necessary) to indicate the old-fashioned method.

A key point to remember is that:

> [Tags are a "folksonomy" not a hierarchy](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/174/914).

In other words, design your tags to be easily-used tools and not a comprehensive taxonomy. Tags should be organic and bottom-up, rather than top-down and mechanical.

Comment: Doesn't this sort of make "manual" and "algorithm" meta-tags, since they're describing (and only useful in combination with) "creation"? (Also I'm really glad you're on the site! :))

Comment: @WendiKidd: Not necessarily. I think was thinking they would be useful on the solutions side: "Is there an automated way to solve a Sudoku problem?" [tag:manual] probably is the default for most question, so I doubt it will be useful.

Comment: Ahh. I was thinking more for creating puzzles, not solving them. Hmm, I need to think about this more.

Answer (score -1):

I say introduce [puzzle-generation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-generation) for computer generation, and [manual-puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual-puzzle-creation) for hand-writing puzzles. We can keep [puzzle-creation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-creation) for questions that don't fall in either.